# The derivative of $\ln(x)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, derivatives, logarithms, power-series

> How can one prove the following by **elementary means**?
>   $$\ln(x)'=\frac{1}{x}$$

Say we know that
$$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}.$$

Comment: Can you prove $(e^x)' = e^x$?  Do you know a rule for derivative of an inverse function?

Comment: You can get more elementary than power series.  Write $f(x) =e^x$ and use the chain rule on $f \circ f^{-1}$.

Comment: Starting from $\exp$, check $\exp'=\exp$, write $x=\exp(\ln(x))$ and differentiate both sides. (This second thing is called the inverse function theorem but you do not need to know that to carry out this proof.)

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you consider to be "elementary" and "non-elementary"?  I'm having difficulty thinking of any proof that I wouldn't consider elementary.  But it seems there is some "non-elementary" proof you are trying to avoid...

Comment: @EricWofsey I consider e.g. the chain rule or derivative of the inverse function as non-elementary steps.

Comment: Not sure how to get this via elementary means if the chain rule is non-elementary.  I suppose you could try the integral-definition of log.

Comment: @Randall Perhaps I was too demanding and the answers now seem OK to me.

Comment: If you want to avoid citing the rule for the derivative of an inverse function, then probably the easiest way is to first prove that rule and then use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)=e^x$, so $f^{-1}(x)=\ln x$.  We know that $(f \circ f^{-1})(x)=x$.  Differentiate by the chain rule to get
$$
f'(f^{-1}(x)) \frac{d}{dx}f^{-1}(x)=1.
$$
As $f'=f$ this boils down to
$$
x \frac{d}{dx}f^{-1}(x)=1
$$
giving what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If we know that, then\begin{align}\exp'(x)&=\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}\right)'\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}\\&=\exp(x).\end{align}Therefore,\begin{align}\ln'(x)&=\frac1{\exp'(\ln(x))}\\&=\frac1{\exp(\ln(x))}\\&=\frac1x.\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=e^x$.  Then:

$${\partial \log (x) \over \partial x} = {\partial f^{-1}(x) \over \partial x} = {1 \over e^{\log(x)}} = 1/x$$.